# How do I copy **kwargs to self?

Tags: python, syntax, constructor, keyword-argument

Is there a way that I can define `__init__` so keywords defined in `**kwargs` are assigned to the class?

For example, if I were to initialize a `ValidationRule` class with `ValidationRule(other='email')`, the value for `self.other` should be added to the class without having to explicitly name every possible kwarg.

```
class ValidationRule:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # code to assign **kwargs to .self
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using new-style classes?

Comment: @Georg: I don't even know what new-style classes are? I'm using Python 2.5 if that's relevant.

Comment: To create a newstyle class you just need to inherit from a newstyle class (usually `object`) so use `class ValidationRule(object):` More info here: http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

Comment: Newstyle..? seems to be old style in python3? is this will even work in there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest way, but it works:

```
class ValidationRule: 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

I think I prefer [ony's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535917/copy-kwargs-to-self/2535952#2535952) because it restricts available properties to keep you out of trouble when your input comes from external sources.

Comment: It won't work correctly if variable is a "magic" one. Consider [propeties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and [slotted objects](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#slots). That applies to both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 37):

I think [somewhere on the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744161/230744) I've seen such solution. Anyway it can look like:

```
class ValidationRule:
    __allowed = ("other", "same", "different")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            assert( k in self.__class__.__allowed )
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

This class will only accept arguments with a whitelisted attribute names listed in `__allowed`.

Comment: ValidationRule is just my base class, and it doesn't have any of its own attributes, so there isn't anything they can accidentally overwrite, but otherwise, this would be a good safe guard ;) I'd probably use a blacklist instead of a whitelist in this case though, so as not to restrict them too much.

Comment: Python-3 renamed `dict.iteritems -> dict.items`, [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems)

Comment: I don't know if this is a python3 issue, but sending an invalid `kwargs` raises `AssertionError` in python 3.8. I used `try...catch` to overcome this

Comment: @Mr.Hobo, you should be able to see source of assertion, and most likely it will lead to line `assert( k in self.__class__.__allowed )` which is there to justify last sentence of the answer about validation and it is the sole role of it ;) I.e. it can be removed if you don't like that or replaced with different way of handling that.

Answer (score 13):

You could do something like this:

```
class ValidationRule:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      for (k, v) in kwargs.items():
         setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: If the kwargs list is long, you might want to use *iteritems()* instead of *items()*. For your purpose that should be fine though.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly What's the difference between `iteritems()` and `items()`?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro In Python 2 `iteritems()`, returns a generator while `items()` returns a list. In Python 3, `items()` returns an itemview and `iteritems()` was removed. I prefer `items()` because it's compatible with both. For very large dicts, I still use `iteritems()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998492/iteritems-in-python

Answer (score 4):

```
class ValidationRule:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set your `kwargs` arguments by updating `__dict__` attribute of the instance.

```
class ValidationRule:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be considered nicer than updating `__dict__`:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        vars(self).update(kwargs)

>>> c = C(a='a', b='b')
>>> c.a   # returns 'a'
>>> c.b   # returns 'b'
```

Comment: why is it nicer?

Answer (score 0):

I found the above answers helpful and then refined:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, key1=1, key2=2, key3=3):
        for (k, v) in locals().iteritems():
            if k != 'self':
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

Test:

```
>>> myobj = MyObj(key1=0)
>>> print myobj.key1
0
```

And validation is also there:

```
>>> myobj = MyObj(key4=4)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key4'
```