# When should iteritems() be used instead of items()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it legitimate to use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` in all places? Why was `iteritems()` removed from Python 3? Seems like a terrific and useful method. What's the reasoning behind it?

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to know what is the correct idiom for iterating over a dictionary in a generator-like way (one item at a time, not all into memory) in a way that is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In Python 2.x - [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returned a list of (key, value) pairs. In Python 3.x, [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) is now an `itemview` object, which behaves differently - so it **has** to be iterated over, or materialised... So, `list(dict.items())` is required for what was `dict.items()` in Python 2.x.

Python 2.7 also has a bit of a back-port for key handling, in that you have [`viewkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys), [`viewitems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) and [`viewvalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues) methods, the most useful being `viewkeys` which behaves more like a `set` (which you'd expect from a `dict`).

Simple example:

```
common_keys = list(dict_a.viewkeys() & dict_b.viewkeys())
```

Will give you a list of the common keys, but again, in Python 3.x - just use `.keys()` instead.

Python 3.x has generally been made to be more "lazy" - i.e. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is now effectively [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), etc.

Comment: It doesn't answer clearly to the question, what should we use instead of .iteritems() ?

Answer (score 116):

`dict.iteritems` was removed because `dict.items` now does the thing `dict.iteritems` did in python 2.x and even improved it a bit by making it an [`itemview`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Comment: There are so many really, really bad Python tutorial sites on the web now that it's easy to get the idea that Python 3 lost functionality over Python 2 (do not read this link: https://www.pythonpool.com/python-iteritems/)

Answer (score 69):

[The six library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) helps with writing code that is compatible with both python 2.5+ and python 3. It has an iteritems method that will work in both python 2 and 3. Example:

```
import six

d = dict( foo=1, bar=2 )

for k, v in six.iteritems(d):
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 13):

As the dictionary documentation for [python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) would tell you, in python 2 `items` returns a list, while `iteritems` returns a iterator.

In python 3, `items` returns a [view](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), which is pretty much the same as an iterator.

If you are using python 2, you may want to user `iteritems` if you are dealing with large dictionaries and all you want to do is iterate over the items (not necessarily copy them to a list)

Comment: I understand that ``iteritems`` is an iterator, which is why it's so useful. I almost never want to iterate over a dictionary as a list. So what's the correct way to iterate over dictionary with something generator like in a way that is compatible with both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: @user248237 `for key in some_dict` works on both - and the `2to3` tool will translate `iteritems()` to `items()` anyway...

Comment: @JonClements: fair enough, though I always thought ``for k in d: d[k]`` is unnecessarily verbose/unpythonic

Answer (score 8):

Just as @Wessie noted, `dict.iteritems`, `dict.iterkeys` and `dict.itervalues` (which return an **iterator** in Python2.x) as well as `dict.viewitems`, `dict.viewkeys` and `dict.viewvalues` (which return **view objects** in Python2.x) were all removed in Python3.x

And `dict.items`, `dict.keys` and `dict.values` used to return a **copy** of the dictionary's list in Python2.x now return **view objects** in Python3.x, *but* they are still not the same as **iterator**.

If you want to return an **iterator** in Python3.x, use [`iter(dictview)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) :

```
$ python3.3

>>> d = {'one':'1', 'two':'2'}
>>> type(d.items())
<class 'dict_items'>
>>>
>>> type(d.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>>
>>>
>>> ii = iter(d.items())
>>> type(ii)
<class 'dict_itemiterator'>
>>>
>>> ik = iter(d.keys())
>>> type(ik)
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>
```

Comment: Which is more efficient when one wants to do an inverse lookup? view objects or iterator?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use `items` instead `iteritems` in all places in Python. For example, the following code:

```
class C:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
  def __iter__(self):
    return self.a.iteritems()

>>> c = C(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))
>>> [v for v in c]
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

will break if you use `items`:

```
class D:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
  def __iter__(self):
    return self.a.items()

>>> d = D(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))
>>> [v for v in d]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __iter__ returned non-iterator of type 'list'
```

The same is true for [viewitems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems), which is available in Python 3.

Also, since [items](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a copy of the dictionary’s list of `(key, value)` pairs, it is less efficient, unless you want to create a copy anyway.

In Python 2, it is best to use `iteritems` for iteration. The `2to3` tool can replace it with `items` if you ever decide to upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 6):

`future.utils` allows for python 2 and 3 compatibility.

```
# Python 2 and 3: option 3
from future.utils import iteritems
heights = {'man': 185,'lady': 165}
for (key, value) in iteritems(heights):
    print(key,value)

>>> ('lady', 165)
>>> ('man', 185)
```

See this link: https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason someone still needs to do this and doesn't want to use a compatibility library, a simple approach is to make a top-level callable that calls the correct one by version:

```
from operator import methodcaller
try:
    {}.viewitems()
except AttributeError:
    # Py3, use items
    viewitems = methodcaller('items')
else:
    viewitems = methodcaller('viewitems')

mydict = {...}
for k, v in viewitems(mydict):
    ...
```

This will behave identically on 2.7 and 3+ (no copying, always gets a live view). You could change all references to `view` from `view` to `iter` to support pre-2.7 Python, though the behavior would differ subtly in some cases (views are iter*ble*s, but not itera*tor*s; you can call `next` on an iterator, but not a non-iterator iterable).

In practice though:

1. At this point Py2 is EOL, so just write for Py3, and
2. If you must support both, write as portably as you can for Py2 (with all the `__future__` imports, explicit `u` and `b` prefixes for text vs. bytes literals, using `io.open` to replace `open`, etc.) and use `2to3` for the little things that you can't directly write portably.