# How do I get a dictionary into a list of all the keys in the following format? (In python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a dictionary

```
{
   'a': [1, 2, 3],
   'b': [4, 5, 6]
}
```

how do I get the output

```
[
   ['a', 1, 2, 3],
   ['b', 4, 5, 6]
]
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: @mauve - You can't store them in order, but you can arrange their keys in a `sorted()` order.

Comment: basically, i need to get them into a list as shown. any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean:

```
>>> a = {
...    'a':[1,2,3],
...    'b':[4,5,6]
... }

>>> [[key]+value for key, value in a.items()]
[['b', 4, 5, 6], ['a', 1, 2, 3]]
```

If you need sorted:

```
>>> sorted([[key]+value for key, value in a.items()])
[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 4, 5, 6]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be closer to what you want (key and values in one list per dictionary item):

```
d = {
   'a':[1,2,3],
   'b':[4,5,6]
}

print sorted([[key] + values for key, values in d.iteritems()])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: dict object has no attribute 'iteritems'.

Comment: @DavidK: [Yes it has](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) (I guess since Python 2.2). But you can use `items()` as well.

Comment: seems Python 3 does not.

Comment: @DavidK: Yep, on Python 3 `items()` return a **generator** like `iteritems()` on Python 2 does. So `iteritems()` has been instead with `items()` since Python 3. Like `range()` and `xrange()`.

Comment: Ok, I found ["In python 3, items returns a view, which is pretty much the same as an iterator."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13998541/3419103)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OrderedDict if you want to get a specific order.

If you want to sort according to the keys :

```
D = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}

[[k] + D[k] for k in sorted(D.keys())]
```