# Getting values from a dict in 2nd field

Tags: python, list, dictionary, get

For example, I have this:

```
alphabetValues = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,"f":6,"g":7...
```

Is it possible if instead of having:

```
print(alphabetValues["c"])
```

To having something that would get "e" if I searched for 5 in a dict.

> "e":5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to get `'e'` from `5`, you have the dictionary the wrong way around...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm already using code which get, for example, 3 if I search for an C. :/

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the opposite, hence wrong way around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reverse / inverse a mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by jonrsharpe, you need to reverse your dictionnary :

```
alphabetValues = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,"f":6,"g":7}

revalpha={v:k for k,v in alphabetValues.iteritems()}

>>> revalpha[5]
'e'
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the help, I'm only just getting to grips with Python.

Comment: This didn't work for me straight away, I've used
    revalpha={v:k for k,v in alphabetValues.items()}
Instead.

Comment: I guess you're running python3. The method iteritems has been removed in version 3 and we now have to use item instead (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998492/iteritems-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up an alphabet list?

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

print(alphabet[0]) #will print out 'a'
print(alphabet[25]) #will print out 'z'
```

Note that all values are 1 less than expected.