# Iterate over dictionary of class containing a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have something like this:

```
class C:
  def get_data(): returns a list

d = {several instances of C}
```

Now, how do I iterate over all elements of all lists? I failed miserably:

```
[e for e in [v.get_data() for _, v in d.items()]]
```

The inner loop will produce a list of lists which can not be digested by the outer loop.

Comment: What is the outer loop doing? Don't you just want `[v.get_data() for v in d.values()]`. What should the output be? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: If you are using python2.7, I would recommend using iteritems/itervalues, as they require less memory.
See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998492/iteritems-in-python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a flatten:

```
[e for _, v in d.items() for e in v.get_data()]
```

Note the order of the loops.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

class C:
  def get_data(self): return ['a','b']

d = {'a' : C(), 'b' : C()}

print [e for e in itertools.chain.from_iterable(v.get_data() for v in d.values())]
```

Will print

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your existing expression -

```
[item for sublist in [v.get_data() for _, v in d.items()] for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 1):

@piokuc's answer is the better option, but in Python 3, `yield from` is a possibility:

```
class C:
    def get_data(self): 
        return ['a','b']


def extract(dict_):
    """Yield elements from sublists."""
    for _, v in dict_.items():
        yield from v.get_data()


d = {'a' : C(), 'b' : C()}
[e for e in extract(d)]
# ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "iterate over all elements", but based on the code in your question, the following will create a `list` of all the elements in both Python 2 & 3 and doesn't require importing anything else:

```
class C:
    def get_data(self): return ['a', 'b']

d = {'a' : C(), 'b' : C()}

print([e for c in d.values() for e in c.get_data()])  # -> ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

In Python 2 you might want to use `d.itervalues()` instead of `d.values()` because it creates an iterator of the values rather than creating a temporary list of them (which is what Python 3 does automatically when the `values()` method called).