# How do I better use the translate function?

Tags: python, string, translate, ord

If I want to use `translate` on more than one unicode character like:

`'banana'.translate({ord('ba'):u'cd'})`

How can I do this? `ord` works on only one character. So what can make this happen?

Note: The solution explained in [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) is not a Python3 compatible solution. I tried to modify the `iteritems` as per [iteritems in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998492/iteritems-in-python) but couldn't make it working. I am new to python I don't know how to make this work.

Comment: I don't think you can, sadly... translate is optimised for character replacements, not substring replacements.

Comment: I understand. But if I want to have alternative implementation what can it be? How can I achieve such a result?

Comment: Is it just this one replacement? Then `banana.replace('ba', 'cd')`.

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm looking for multiple replacements.

Comment: It's not clear wether you want to replace "ba" with "cd" or replace "b" with "c" and "a" with "d" or something else...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)

Comment: "ord works on only one character" - I understand this already and the above comments clarifies further.

Comment: The solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) is not for python 3!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build your own function, mocking the translate behaviour:

```
def trans_mock(string, **kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        string= string.replace(k,v)
    return string
```

Where kwargs will be the strings you want to replace:

```
print trans_mock("banana", ba="cd", na="we") # output: cdwewe
```

you may even want to *sortof* override the string class and add trans_mock as method:

```
class string(str):
    def trans_mock(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            print k,v
            self = self.replace(k,v)
        return self

banana = string("banana")
print banana.trans_mock(ba="ct", na="lw") # output: ctlwlw
```