# Function to check if object-dtype column value is float or string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-defined-types, isinstance

I am trying to write a function which is equal to isnumber[column] function in excel

dataset:

```
feature1 feature2 feature3
  123       1.07     1
  231       2.08     3
  122        ab      4
  111       3.04     6
  555        cde     8

feature1: integer dtype
feature2: object dtype
feature3: integer dtype
```

I tried this piece of code

```
for item in df.feature2.iteritems():
    if isinstance(item, float):
       print('yes')
    else:
       print('no')
```

I got the result as

```
 no
 no
 no
 no
 no
```

But i want the result as

```
yes
yes
no
yes
no
```

When i tried to check the type of individual feature2 values, this is what see

```
type(df.feature2[0]) = str
type(df.feature2[1]) = str
type(df.feature2[2]) = str
type(df.feature2[3]) = str
type(df.feature2[4]) = str

But clearly 0,1,3 should be shown as float, but they show up as str
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Iteritems is returning a tuple, `((123, '1.07'), 1.07)` and since you want to loop over each value try the below code.
You just need to remove `.iteritems()` and it will work like a charm.

```
df['feature2']=[1.07,2.08,'ab',3.04,'cde']
for item in df.feature2:
    if isinstance(item,float):
       print('yes')
    else:
       print('no')
```

Here is your output:

```
yes
yes
no
yes
no
```

Comment: If it helps, please care to accept and upvote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @SaiSumanth Can you tell me what's the error? I included the data frame creation line that I used for testing and it is working from me. Also, I am using Python3

Comment: Its working now, actually my features values were in 'float string' type instead of float type. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things you need to consider here:

1. Methods for `Dict` vs `DataFrame`
2. Difference between dtype (array-scalar types) and type (built-in Python types) - Reference (https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

**Point 1:**

`.iteritems()` / `.items()` are methods for dictionaries, whereas if you're dealing with dtypes (and judging by the data you've provided), you're likely to be going through a DataFrame, in which you don't need to use the `.iteritems()` method to loop through each value. Side note, `.iteritems()` has been phased out by Python and is replaced by `.items()` (See discussion: [When should iteritems() be used instead of items()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998492/when-should-iteritems-be-used-instead-of-items))

**Point 2:**

When using numpy or Pandas, the data type of values imported into the DataFrames are called `dtypes`. These need to be differentiated from their direct comparisons in Pythons, which Python refers to as just `type`. You should use the table under "**Pandas Data Types**" heading for mapping of `dtype` to `type` (Ref: https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html)

Now, in response to your question, this bit of code should solve your issue:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']
data = [[123, 1.07, 1],
        [231, 2.08, 3],
        [122, 'ab', 4],
        [111, 3.04, 6],
        [555, 'cde', 8]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

for value in df.feature2:
    if isinstance(value,float):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(df["feature2"])):
    test = df.loc[i,"feature2"]
    if isinstance(test, float):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: bear in mind that this just tests for floats - if you want any number, float or integer, you'd have to change the third line to      if isinstance(test, float) or isinstance(test, int):

Answer (score 0):

This is because `iteritems()` returns a tuple which is the `(index, value)`. 
So you are trying to check for example if `(0, 1.07)` or `(1, 2.08)` are of type float, which they aren't of course.

It should work if you change `df.feature2.iteritems()` to `df.feature2.values` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

columns = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']
data = [[123, 1.07, 1],
 [231, 2.08, 3],
 [122, 'ab', 4],
 [111, 3.04, 6],
 [555, 'cde', 8]]

df_ = df(data, columns=columns)
types = []
for k in df_:
    a = set(type(m) for m in df_[k])
    if len(a) > 1:
        types.append({k: 'object'})
    else:
        types.append({k: str(list(a)[0].__name__)})

print(types)
```

Output:

```
[{'feature1': 'int'}, {'feature2': 'object'}, {'feature3': 'int'}]
```