# construct instance variables from dictionnay

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a class, in which the constructor receives a dictionary, as shown in the following code:

```
class Test:
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           for key, value in kwargs.items():
               self.key = value
```

what i want to do at the end is the ability to reference each key as shown in the following piece of code:

```
T = Test(age=34, name='david')
print(T.age)
```

instead i get keyword can't be an expression..

Comment: this subject could benefit from a performance discussion, which method is more effecient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the class dict:

```
class Test:
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

---

You can also query `vars` and update (one should prefer this to invoking `__dunder__` attributes directly).

```
class Test:
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           vars(self).update(kwargs)
```

Comment: this is cleaner than using `setattr`. +1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739625/setattr-with-kwargs-pythonic-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You are setting only the attribute `T.key`. If you want to dynamically set attributes based on the name of the key, you need `setattr`:

```
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: Magic method `__getattr__` works too.


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.keywords = kwargs
    
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.keywords[key]

Comment: @PierreGeier Avoid using dunder methods.